BOLT12 merchant-pays-user flow: how does a merchant know the `invoice_node_id` of the person it received the `invoice` from in advance?
BOLT12 has a merchant-pays-user flow (https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/247e83d528a2a380e533e89f31918d7b0ce6a0c1/12-offer-encoding.md?plain=1#L54). In this, the merchant receives an invoice (in response to its invoice_request) and confirms the invoice_node_id to ensure it's about to pay the correct person, and makes a payment to the invoice (https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/247e83d528a2a380e533e89f31918d7b0ce6a0c1/12-offer-encoding.md?plain=1#L58).
How does a merchant know the invoice_node_id of the person if received the invoice from in advance, especially if the invoice_request was presented via e-mail, NFC, QR, etc. and not from an offer? Seems like the signature field from the invoice_request needs to be copied over to the invoice and verify that way.
OR, is this workflow meant for a refund only (and not a general purpose payout) and there is an original invoice that the refund workflow is referring to? If so, it still seems like there should be a signature involved and not rely on an invoice_node_id.
